# Unwanted cursor flicker when cursor moves inside regions

Tags: vb.net

The following code example paints three rectangles and changes the cursor type to hand/default if the mouse is inside/outside the rectangular regions respectively. The program executes as intended with one exception: when located inside a region, the mouse flickers while being moved.

Having investigated, it seems the issue may relate to a contradiction between my code and an underlying control, with respect to which mouse type to display, resulting in flicker. Whether correct or not, unfortunately I've been unable to resolve the issue. Please can you help?

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1
    Private myRectangles() As Rectangle
    Private myRegions(2) As Region

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Write an array of rectangles.
        myRectangles = {New Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50), New Rectangle(200, 200, 50, 50), New Rectangle(300, 300, 50, 50)}

        ' Write an array of rectangle regions.
        For i As Integer = 0 To myRegions.length - 1
            Dim myPath As New GraphicsPath
            myPath.AddRectangle(myRectangles(i))

            Dim myRegion As New Region(myPath)
            myRegions(i) = myRegion
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        ' Iterate myRegions to check if the mouse is over a region.
        For i As Integer = 0 To myRegions.Count - 1
            Dim IsHit As Boolean = myRegions(i).IsVisible(e.Location)

            If IsHit Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand
                Exit For
            Else
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        ' Paint myRectangles.
        For i As Integer = 0 To myRegions.Length - 1
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Black, 1), myRectangles(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT1: The above MouseMove Sub can be simplified to the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    ' Check if the mouse is located within any region.
    Dim isHit As Boolean = myRegions.Any(Function(p) p.IsVisible(e.Location))

    If isHit Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand
    Else
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT2: Revised complete code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1
    Private myRectangles() As Rectangle
    Private myGraphicsPaths As New List(Of GraphicsPath)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Write a graphics path list of rectangles.
        myRectangles = {New Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50), New Rectangle(200, 200, 50, 50), New Rectangle(300, 300, 50, 50)}

        For i As Integer = 0 To myRectangles.Length - 1
            Dim myPath As New GraphicsPath
            myPath.AddRectangle(myRectangles(i))
            myGraphicsPaths.Add(myPath)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        ' Check if the mouse is located within any graphicspath.
        Dim isHit As Boolean = myGraphicsPaths.Any(Function(p) p.IsVisible(e.Location))

        If isHit And Cursor.Current IsNot Cursors.Hand Then
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand
        Else
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        ' Paint myRectangles.
        For i As Integer = 0 To myRectangles.Length - 1
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Black, 1), myRectangles(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the use of these Regions? From what you're showing here, it looks like you're using the array of Regions just to check whether the Mouse Pointer is inside one. You could instead handle a `List(Of GraphicsPath)` and use `AddRectangle()` to add your Recctangle shapes. With this list, you just check whether `dim isVisible = [YourListOfGraphicsPaths].Any(Function(p) p.IsVisble([Point]))`. If true, set a type of Cursor - only if it's not already set - otherwise, change it with another.

Comment: Hi Jimi. The above code is an excerpt from a program that will analyse truss bridges. The user will input in a datagridview the coordinates for truss nodes, i.e. the location where truss members intersect. Truss nodes will be painted as circles; in due course truss members will be painted as rectangles. I wish for the mouse cursor type to change to 'hand' when the user mouses over a node/member and for the respective node/member number in the datagridview to be selected, and also for the visual cue of being able to 'select' a node/member.

Comment: In any event, it seems your suggestion, while simplifying my code, does not resolve the issue... unless List(Of...) does something I'm unaware of. Refer above to the simplified code for the MouseMove Sub.

Comment: You missed the point. You have some shapes (Rectangles), and this is what you use for drawing. It's already wrong, since you need to handle these shapes, not just *paint* them. So, as it appears, to manage these shapes, you introduce a new collection of Regions derived from GraphicsPath object (that you never dispose of) just to use the `Isvisible()` method. I'm suggesting to ditch the Regions and Rectangles collection and just use a `List(Of GraphicsPath)` for all, to simplify the procedure. -- Then, I also suggested to only set the Cursor if it's different from the current, not in any case.

Comment: You're drawing on the surface of a Form. Even assuming that the Form is DoubleBuffered, I suggest not to use its surface for drawing. Use a DoubleBuffered Control, as a PictureBox or a flat Label, both double-buffered on their own. -- In any case, don't use Regions to determine whether a Point is contained in a shape. The GraphicsPath provides the same method, plus the `IsOutlineVisible` method, similar, but only related to the border of the Path. -- I doubt that you only need 3 Rectangles,  clearly many more, so the calculations must be as fast as possible.

Comment: You need to avoid to set the same Cursor over and over because the Framework doesn't verify whether the Cursor you're setting is the same as the current, so it sets it every time. And every time part of the drawing needs to be repainted. So, the test is on you.

Comment: Good news: My code is getting more concise! Bad news: My issue remains. I've posted above the revised complete code. A few comments: (1)  Not sure how the rectangles can be ditched given their requirement for path creation? (2) Fair point (no pun intended) re setting the cursor only if different -- this was sloppy of me (3) In the actual program I'm not painting on the form itself (4) Doublebuffered does not resolve the issue (tried it already) (5) Agreed on a desire for calculations to be as quick as possible, but there will typically be tens of points, not hundreds or more, so not critical.

Comment: 1. As described, use **only** a `List(Of GraphicsPath)` for everything: drawing and Mouse Pointer checks (but, you should use a class Handler for this, which includes the logic required for drawing and any other validation / analysis / bounds check etc.) 2. Set a new Cursor if and only if the previous Cursor is **not the same** you have determined is the *right one*: setting twice `Cursors.Hand` is the same as setting two different cursors. E.g., if the Pointer is inside the bounds of a Path **and** the Cursor **is already** a `Cursors.Hand`, just return (don't set it).

Comment: 3. You're still using a Form as Canvas 4. I don't see when / where / how the Canvas is invalidated.

Comment: @Jimi With respect to your points: 1 - I know how to add/remove event Handlers, but don't understand your reference to "class" handler, sorry. 2 - I've tweaked the EDIT 2 code above. I think this achieves the result you describe.

Comment: 3 - As mentioned previously, the above code is just an example to illustrate my issue; in the actual program painting is performed on a Panel, itself located on a Tab Control, on a Form. I accept that in the above example I do not invalidate the form, but in the actual program I do. This does not resolve my issue. I’m not sure that painting itself has any relevance, given that the hit-test is performed independent of it -- I could comment out painting altogether and still my issue would exist.